# Can I have a source statement inside a cron file ?

Tags: linux, syntax, cron

can I place a source line inside a cron file like this..

source \feadb.cnf
and then schedule the rest of the jobs like this...

30 10 * * * $feadb/SlowQueries/run.sh

Comment: StackOverflow is for helping with coding problems, not to do OS specific testing/research for you. Please update your Q with your research on the problem, or read the http://stackoverflow.com/help before posting another Q. Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

You can make another script and put both "source \feadb.cnf" and your shell script "feadb/SlowQueries/run.sh" there then schedule your new script with cron instead of the orginal one.